# how do I get jenkins to deploy a branch?

Tags: jenkins

I want Jenkins to clone a git repo checkout a branch and deploy that branch to a CI environment. How do I get Jenkins to checkout a branch I specify to it via a build parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use git command "git checkout -b branch" in Jenkins console.

Execute shell (linux environment)

```
   git checkout -b $(branch)
```

Execute batch for windows

```
   git checkout -b %branch%
```

Pass **branch** as build parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Git plugin, and use a string parameter to specify the branch, then you can set the branch specifier to "*/${my_branch}" - note that you must use this format on Windows too.

Comment: I think the format you mentioned above "*/${my_branch}" is not correct. The correct format is: "${Branch_Name}"

Comment: I tested it and it works.  Can't check jenkins version at the moment. Note that it must resolve to a valid ref (yours might be too)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely execute shell or batch like Mahi suggested. If you are using GIT SCM Plugin all you need to do is provide the branch name in the **Branches to build** section in this format: **${BRANCH_Name}**